# For loop behaviour not as expected, looping multiple times [ MongoDB, Nodejs ]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

Code :- 1

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {

  // var whichDay = dayFormated.dayFormated();
  //
  // console.log(whichDay);
  Item.find({}, function(err, itemsFound) {

    if (itemsFound.length === 0) {
      console.log(itemsFound.length);
      console.log("i Am Here if condition.");
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err) {
        console.log("I am inside insertMany");
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Successfully inserted default values to DB");
        }
      });
      **res.redirect('/');**
      console.log("exiting if bye :P");
    } else {
      console.log("back again at redirect");
      // console.log(itemsFound);
      res.render('list', {
        titleToDoList: "Today",
        itemslist: itemsFound
      });
    }

  });

});
```

### Console log:- 1

```
0
i Am Here if condition.
exiting if bye :P
0
i Am Here if condition.
exiting if bye :P
0
i Am Here if condition.
exiting if bye :P
0
i Am Here if condition.
exiting if bye :P
0
i Am Here if condition.
exiting if bye :P
0
i Am Here if condition.
exiting if bye :P
0
i Am Here if condition.
exiting if bye :P
0
i Am Here if condition.
exiting if bye :P
0
i Am Here if condition.
exiting if bye :P
0
i Am Here if condition.
exiting if bye :P
I am inside insertMany
Successfully inserted default values to DB
back again at redirect
I am inside insertMany
{ BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: todolistDB.items index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbb') }
    at OrderedBulkOperation.handleWriteError (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:1257:9)
    at resultHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:521:23)
    at handler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:942:24)
    at fn (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:356:13)
    at handleOperationResult (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:558:5)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:277:5)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at processIncomingData (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:399:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:299:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:710:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
  name: 'BulkWriteError',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  writeErrors: [ WriteError { err: [Object] } ],
  result:
   BulkWriteResult {
     result:
      { ok: 1,
        writeErrors: [Array],
        writeConcernErrors: [],
        insertedIds: [Array],
        nInserted: 0,
        nUpserted: 0,
        nMatched: 0,
        nModified: 0,
        nRemoved: 0,
        upserted: [] } },
  insertedDocs:
   [ { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbc, itemName: 'Wakeup', __v: 0 },
     { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbd, itemName: 'Bath', __v: 0 } ] }
I am inside insertMany
{ BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: todolistDB.items index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbb') }
    at OrderedBulkOperation.handleWriteError (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:1257:9)
    at resultHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:521:23)
    at handler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:942:24)
    at fn (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:356:13)
    at handleOperationResult (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:558:5)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:277:5)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at processIncomingData (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:399:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:299:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:710:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
  name: 'BulkWriteError',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  writeErrors: [ WriteError { err: [Object] } ],
  result:
   BulkWriteResult {
     result:
      { ok: 1,
        writeErrors: [Array],
        writeConcernErrors: [],
        insertedIds: [Array],
        nInserted: 0,
        nUpserted: 0,
        nMatched: 0,
        nModified: 0,
        nRemoved: 0,
        upserted: [] } },
  insertedDocs:
   [ { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbc, itemName: 'Wakeup', __v: 0 },
     { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbd, itemName: 'Bath', __v: 0 } ] }
I am inside insertMany
{ BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: todolistDB.items index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbb') }
    at OrderedBulkOperation.handleWriteError (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:1257:9)
    at resultHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:521:23)
    at handler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:942:24)
    at fn (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:356:13)
    at handleOperationResult (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:558:5)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:277:5)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at processIncomingData (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:399:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:299:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:710:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
  name: 'BulkWriteError',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  writeErrors: [ WriteError { err: [Object] } ],
  result:
   BulkWriteResult {
     result:
      { ok: 1,
        writeErrors: [Array],
        writeConcernErrors: [],
        insertedIds: [Array],
        nInserted: 0,
        nUpserted: 0,
        nMatched: 0,
        nModified: 0,
        nRemoved: 0,
        upserted: [] } },
  insertedDocs:
   [ { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbc, itemName: 'Wakeup', __v: 0 },
     { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbd, itemName: 'Bath', __v: 0 } ] }
I am inside insertMany
{ BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: todolistDB.items index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbb') }
    at OrderedBulkOperation.handleWriteError (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:1257:9)
    at resultHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:521:23)
    at handler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:942:24)
    at fn (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:356:13)
    at handleOperationResult (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:558:5)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:277:5)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at processIncomingData (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:399:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:299:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:710:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
  name: 'BulkWriteError',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  writeErrors: [ WriteError { err: [Object] } ],
  result:
   BulkWriteResult {
     result:
      { ok: 1,
        writeErrors: [Array],
        writeConcernErrors: [],
        insertedIds: [Array],
        nInserted: 0,
        nUpserted: 0,
        nMatched: 0,
        nModified: 0,
        nRemoved: 0,
        upserted: [] } },
  insertedDocs:
   [ { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbc, itemName: 'Wakeup', __v: 0 },
     { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbd, itemName: 'Bath', __v: 0 } ] }
I am inside insertMany
{ BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: todolistDB.items index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbb') }
    at OrderedBulkOperation.handleWriteError (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:1257:9)
    at resultHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:521:23)
    at handler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:942:24)
    at fn (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:356:13)
    at handleOperationResult (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:558:5)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:277:5)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at processIncomingData (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:399:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:299:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:710:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
  name: 'BulkWriteError',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  writeErrors: [ WriteError { err: [Object] } ],
  result:
   BulkWriteResult {
     result:
      { ok: 1,
        writeErrors: [Array],
        writeConcernErrors: [],
        insertedIds: [Array],
        nInserted: 0,
        nUpserted: 0,
        nMatched: 0,
        nModified: 0,
        nRemoved: 0,
        upserted: [] } },
  insertedDocs:
   [ { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbc, itemName: 'Wakeup', __v: 0 },
     { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbd, itemName: 'Bath', __v: 0 } ] }
I am inside insertMany
{ BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: todolistDB.items index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbb') }
    at OrderedBulkOperation.handleWriteError (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:1257:9)
    at resultHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:521:23)
    at handler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:942:24)
    at fn (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:356:13)
    at handleOperationResult (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:558:5)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:277:5)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at processIncomingData (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:399:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:299:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:710:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
  name: 'BulkWriteError',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  writeErrors: [ WriteError { err: [Object] } ],
  result:
   BulkWriteResult {
     result:
      { ok: 1,
        writeErrors: [Array],
        writeConcernErrors: [],
        insertedIds: [Array],
        nInserted: 0,
        nUpserted: 0,
        nMatched: 0,
        nModified: 0,
        nRemoved: 0,
        upserted: [] } },
  insertedDocs:
   [ { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbc, itemName: 'Wakeup', __v: 0 },
     { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbd, itemName: 'Bath', __v: 0 } ] }
I am inside insertMany
{ BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: todolistDB.items index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbb') }
    at OrderedBulkOperation.handleWriteError (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:1257:9)
    at resultHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:521:23)
    at handler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:942:24)
    at fn (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:356:13)
    at handleOperationResult (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:558:5)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:277:5)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at processIncomingData (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:399:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:299:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:710:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
  name: 'BulkWriteError',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  writeErrors: [ WriteError { err: [Object] } ],
  result:
   BulkWriteResult {
     result:
      { ok: 1,
        writeErrors: [Array],
        writeConcernErrors: [],
        insertedIds: [Array],
        nInserted: 0,
        nUpserted: 0,
        nMatched: 0,
        nModified: 0,
        nRemoved: 0,
        upserted: [] } },
  insertedDocs:
   [ { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbc, itemName: 'Wakeup', __v: 0 },
     { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbd, itemName: 'Bath', __v: 0 } ] }
I am inside insertMany
{ BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: todolistDB.items index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbb') }
    at OrderedBulkOperation.handleWriteError (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:1257:9)
    at resultHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:521:23)
    at handler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:942:24)
    at fn (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:356:13)
    at handleOperationResult (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:558:5)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:277:5)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at processIncomingData (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:399:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:299:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:710:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
  name: 'BulkWriteError',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  writeErrors: [ WriteError { err: [Object] } ],
  result:
   BulkWriteResult {
     result:
      { ok: 1,
        writeErrors: [Array],
        writeConcernErrors: [],
        insertedIds: [Array],
        nInserted: 0,
        nUpserted: 0,
        nMatched: 0,
        nModified: 0,
        nRemoved: 0,
        upserted: [] } },
  insertedDocs:
   [ { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbc, itemName: 'Wakeup', __v: 0 },
     { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbd, itemName: 'Bath', __v: 0 } ] }
I am inside insertMany
{ BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: todolistDB.items index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbb') }
    at OrderedBulkOperation.handleWriteError (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:1257:9)
    at resultHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:521:23)
    at handler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:942:24)
    at fn (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:356:13)
    at handleOperationResult (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:558:5)
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:277:5)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at processIncomingData (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (My_Project_Directorynode_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:399:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:299:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:710:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
  name: 'BulkWriteError',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  writeErrors: [ WriteError { err: [Object] } ],
  result:
   BulkWriteResult {
     result:
      { ok: 1,
        writeErrors: [Array],
        writeConcernErrors: [],
        insertedIds: [Array],
        nInserted: 0,
        nUpserted: 0,
        nMatched: 0,
        nModified: 0,
        nRemoved: 0,
        upserted: [] } },
  insertedDocs:
   [ { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbc, itemName: 'Wakeup', __v: 0 },
     { _id: 5f55f40136e7195ed7614bbd, itemName: 'Bath', __v: 0 } ] }
```

---

Code :- 2

```
Item.find({}, function(err, itemsFound) {

    if (itemsFound.length === 0) {
      console.log(itemsFound.length);
      console.log("i Am Here if condition.");
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err) {
        console.log("I am inside insertMany");
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Successfully inserted default values to DB");
          **res.redirect('/');**
        }
      });
      console.log("exiting if bye :P");
    } else {
      console.log("back again at redirect");
      // console.log(itemsFound);
      res.render('list', {
        titleToDoList: "Today",
        itemslist: itemsFound
      });
    }

  });

});
```

### Console log:- 2

```
    [nodemon] 2.0.4
    [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
    [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
    [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
    [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
    server running on port 3000
    0
    i Am Here if condition.
    exiting if bye :P
    I am inside insertMany
    Successfully inserted default values to DB
    back again at redirect
```

---

code 2 is working perfectly fine, but code 1 it's looping multiple times. Can someone explain to me why code one is looping multiple times? I bolded the place of code to check for reference. Thank you!.

see logs I have pasted, which explains the scenario.

Comment: I don't see a single `for` loop in the code you've posted.

Comment: Sorry, I was saying about the Model.insertMany() inside app.get("/") it keeps on looping. Do refer to the logs I have pasted as a reference.

Comment: Well, in the `/` route, you redirect to `/` so it will just keep running itself over and over again.  You need to send a response, not just redirect right back to the same route over and over again.

Comment: have you taken a look into the log file it's repeating  { 0 i Am Here if condition.
exiting if bye :P } multiple time when I did redirect out of the callback function.

Comment: Yeah.  You keep calling `res.redirect("/")` every time it goes in there which just makes the route get called over and over again.  What part of that do you not see as wrong and a cause of a problem?

Comment: code flow: do nodejs work differently than other languages ?
  if (..) {
    if(condition) {
      statements
    }
    //exits nested if and continue
    redirect("/"); // still inside main if and it has to be executed. [This doesn't work as it's flow has to be ]
  }

Comment: `if` statements in Javascript work just like they do in other languages.  This whole question has me baffled.  What EXACTLY does not work as you expect it to?  Perhaps you're confused by the asynchronous callback to `Item.insertMany()` that  is non-blocking and gets called some indeterminate time in the future?

Comment: yes, I was confused about asynchronous callback, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding as answer since can't comment.

Code 1 is looping multiple times because `res.redirect('/')` is outside the callback function of `Item.insertMany`.

This is a classic example of nodejs asynchronous behaviour. When the code reaches the mongo query, it fires the callback and it lands in the callback queue waiting for response from the database.

So nodejs moves to the next block of code outside the callback, which is `res.redirect('/')`. This makes the code call the `'/'` endpoint again. And until the insert db operation is completed (which will make the length greater than 0), your code always finds the length as 0 and keeps hitting `/` endpoint in a loop.

Comment: Thank you Siddharth, I'm new to nodejs have a bit of confusion about how the code flow works in node, I really appreciate your effort man.